# Bash Script Execute ViM Command is Seemingly Not Interpreting the '$' Command

Tags: bash, vim, here-document

I'm trying to move a certain ViM command into a Linux Bash script. In ViM the command is

```
:g/^SOMEWORD$/d
```

To delete any lines containing only some word and nothing else.

When I move it into a bash script it doesn't work anymore

```
vim -e -s /tmp/file.txt << EOF
    :g/^SOMEWORD$/d
    :update
    :quit
EOF
```

Escaping the `$` doesn't seem to make a difference, is there another way to use the `$` in this type of scenario or am I missing something else?

```
vim -e -s /tmp/file.txt << EOF
    :g/^SOMEWORD\$/d
    :update
    :quit
EOF
```

Comment: Are you sure the lines contain just SOMEWORD and nothing else? Does the file have *nix style newlines?

Comment: Yeah can't reproduce this - even unescaped `$` works for me (perhaps because `/d` isn't a legal variable name?). Replacing `vim -e -s /tmp/file.txt` with a simple `cat` confirms the `$` is being passed through the heredoc

Comment: What's weird is that in regular ViM editor on the same file the command works

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the `$`? if you run the script without the `$` does it then delete lines containing SOMEWORD anywhere on the line?

Comment: If you single-quote the starting `EOF` it will avoid interpretation/evaluation of things that look like variables. So `vim -e -s /tmp/file.txt << 'EOF'`. Please try this and see if it helps. (At any event it will avoid the need for `\$` instead of `$`.)

Comment: @choroba since `vim` can autodetect unix/dos lineendings this _shouldn't_ be an issue here

Comment: @mattb yes it does, it only stops working when the $ is included. What else is odd is that it seems to work on on files created in Linux but not files transferred from Windows

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why but editing the file directly in ViM was treating it as a Unix file but editing through the here-doc was treating it as a DOS file. I found this really handy tool that fixed the issue though

```
`yum install dos2unix`
dos2unix ./filename.txt
```

This looks like it makes the file compliant with Unix file standards

Comment: Maybe you used a Windows Editor to create the file. This would insert CR+LF instead of LF only as a Unix Editor would do.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm just stumped as to why regular ViM was happy with it and it only failed when doing it with the `vim -e -s` method